# Text to floating point: how does it work

Tags: floating-point

Say, I write down in a programming language the characters 5.4 and store it into a double variable. How exactly does a computer decide what floating point representation (mantissa and exponent) is the closest to that number?

Comment: Lovely question, but I think it might belong to a different SE site.

Comment: the question is asked often: see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85223/how-to-manually-parse-a-floating-point-number-from-a-string/85526#85526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once described this, in a simple, easily understood way, for the value 5.2, see [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910115/how-to-represent-float-number-in-memory-in-c/6911412#6911412).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the compiler or interpreter of the programming language uses an algorithm to convert from a decimal string representation to a (binary) floating point representation.

One implementation is David Gay's strtod() at http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c .

Note that while Gay's code is the basis for many implementations of strtod() and snprintf() in widely used C libraries, the code as such suffers from a number of issues and should not be used as such. But, it's instructive as a self-contained example.