# Writing my own float parser

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to write a parser in C and part of its job is to convert a series of characters into a double.  Up to now I have been using strtod but I find it to be quite dangerous and it won't handle cases where the number is at the end of the buffer, which is not null terminated.

I thought I'd write my own.  If I have a string representation of a number of the form a.b, will I be nieve to think that I can just calculate (double)a + ((double)b / (double)10^n), where n is the number of digits in b?

For example, 23.4563:

a = 23
  b = 4563

final answer: 23 + (4563/10000)

Or would that produce inaccurate results with regard to the IEEE format of floats?

Comment: For one, if `b` is an integer type, `b / 10^n` is going to get rounded before being cast to `float`. You'd want to put the cast _inside_ the parentheses. Also, you'd need to make sure that there is no integer overflow in either of `a` or `b`.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right - typo on my part.  I will edit it.

Comment: More to think about : Negative numbers, Exponent format `1.2E10`. negative exponents,... I *really* suggest you just copy into a null terminated buffer and let strtod do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Calculating `a + b/10000.f` will not always produce a correctly rounded result. (For these purposes, the “correctly rounded result” is the one nearest the mathematical value.) An example is “1.0097”. `1 + 97/10000.f` produces 1.0097000598907470703125, but the closer, and correct, `float`, is 1.00969994068145751953125. The incorrect result occurs because there is one rounding in the division and another in the addition. The rounding in the division loses information that shows the other value would have been desired in the addition.

Comment: Your question says your job is to convert to a **double** but elsewhere refers to casting to **float**. You should clarify what type you want to produce.

Comment: An example where `a+b/10000.` fails to produce the correct `double` is 1.0131.

Comment: Don't. Either copy to a null terminated buffer or get and adapt an existing correct implementation.

Comment: I suggest you start reading http://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/convert-to-binary/ . Stop as soon as you don't feel like implementing your own decimal-to-floating-point conversion anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to read floating-point numerals accurately, in the sense that there are various problems that must be carefully addressed, and many people fail to do so. However, it is a solved problem. To start, see [*How to read floating point numbers accurately*, June 1990, by William D. Clinger](https://doi.org/10.1145/93548.93557).

I agree with Roddy, you are likely better off copying the data into a buffer and using existing library functions. (However, you should check that your C implementation provides correctly rounded conversion of floating-point numerals. The C standard does not require it, and some implementations do not provide it.)

Comment: The paper at the link is gone. archive.org still had it: https://web.archive.org/web/20170329102230/http://www.cesura17.net/~will/Professional/Research/Papers/howtoread.pdf It seems to be "How to Read Floating-Point Numbers Accurately." by William D. Clinger https://doi.org/10.1145/93548.93557 https://dblp.org/rec/conf/pldi/Clinger90

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [this answer of mine to a somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455604/968261).

The parser in that answer converts decimal floating point numbers (represented as strings) into IEEE-754 floats and doubles with proper rounding.

As far as I remember, about the only issue in the code is that it may not handle the cases when the exponent part is too big (doesn't fit into an integer) and should amount to returning either an error or `INF`.

Otherwise, it should give you a good idea of what to do (if you have any idea at all of what you're doing:).

Comment: Nice code. One remark though: you say “the cases when the exponent part is too big (doesn't fit into an integer) and should amount to returning either an error or INF.” That's funny, because I too wrote my own decimal to floating-point function (a shorter one than yours because I was able to rely on an existing bigint implementation), and I made the same mistake as you, that is, assuming that an exponent too large to fit in an int means the float is an infinite. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Funny-floating-point-bugs-in-Frama-C-Oxygen-s-front-end

Answer (score 1):

As already said, it's difficult, you need extra precision, etc...

But if you have restricted inputs, and want to know if you can still correctly convert these restricted decimal to binary with semi naive algorithm and standard IEEE 754 ops, you might be interested in my answer to

[How to manually parse a floating point number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85223/how-to-manually-parse-a-floating-point-number-from-a-string/11705617#11705617)